# Can I have multiple Grunt files

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

Is this possible to have two Gruntfiles.js in the same folder, one with the default name and second with for example Gruntfile-second.js ? If it is, how can i run the second one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `grunt --gruntfile Gruntfile-second.js` to run the second file.

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    require('./Gruntfile-second.js')(grunt);
};
```